# Create a Data frame based on DF2 exceeding DF1 with the same rows and line (special merge with condition)

Tags: r, merge, combinations

Before I submit my question here I looked for similar question but I didn't find similar result like I want. 
I have two data Frame Tables in the rows has the same dates (year) and in the line the same companies but each dataframe explain a variable and the values inside the tables are a classification with letters:

```
(BM) Dataframe 

Name | X1992 | X1993 | X1994 | X1995     
---- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----
xyze |  Na   |   Na  |   B   |  B
zyea |  A    |   B   |   B   |  A
ddfa |  Na   |   Na  |   D   |  D
arer |  C    |   C   |   A   |  A
zaer |  Na   |   A   |   A   |  B
wxcv |  A    |   A   |   B   |  A
lklj |  B    |   D   |   D   |  D
jgie |  B    |   B   |   C   |  C
azer |  C    |   B   |   C   |  B
lmoz |  Na   |   Na  |   Na  |  A
jzea |  D    |   D   |   D   |  C

(Size) Dataframe

Name | X1992 | X1993 | X1994 | X1995     
----   -----   -----   -----   ----
xyze   Na      Na      D       C
zyea   B       D       A       A
ddfa   Na      Na      D       C
arer   A       A       C       C
zaer   Na      A       A       D
wxcv   C       B       C       A
lklj   C       C       B       D
jgie   D       B       C       D
azer   B       A       A       B
lmoz   Na      Na      Na      C
jzea   A       D       A       B
```

I would like to have a results like this below
(example: companies with BM "A" & Size "C")

```
>A_C
Name | X1992 | X1993 | X1994 | X1995     
----   -----   -----   -----   ----
xyze   .        .      .       .
zyea   .        .      .       .
ddfa   .        .      .       .
arer   .        .      .       T
zaer   .        .      T       .
wxcv   T        .      .       .
lklj   .        .      .       .
jgie   .        .      .       .
azer   .        .      .       .
lmoz   .        .      .       T
jzea   .        .      .       .
```

This a small projection with the reality.

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the examples.  Try `Map(function(x,y) x %in% c('A', 'C')  & y %in% c('A', 'C'),  BM[-1], Size[-1])`

Comment: It might also help you to read [this note](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) on tidy data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by comparing the corresponding columns with `Map`

```
data.frame(Map(function(x,y) x %in% "A" & y %in% "C", BM[-1], Size[-1]))
```

Here, the output will be a `data.frame` with logical columns that have TRUE elements when the column element in 'BM' is 'A' and 'Size' is 'C'.  All other cases will be FALSE

NOTE: Here, we are assuming that Na are `NA` and it is a typo